# How to view logs in remote shell via ssh through a script and stay there on pressing ctrl + C

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to automate a simple task that I have to repeatedly do on a daily basis: **view logs after ssh to a remote server**.

I have written a script to do that but the problem is, if at any point while viewing logs if I press `ctrl + C`, it logs me out of the server. So here's the flow that I do manually:

1. `ssh -t -p port_num user@remote`
2. `sudo su`
3. `docker logs -f service_name`

Then I sometimes also press `ctrl + C` to execute some commands on remote server and then I get back to watching logs again.

In an attempt to automate the three steps above, I have tried several methods and it works too, but whenever I press `ctrl + C`, it doesn't stay on remote and drops the connection.

Here's what I've tried so far:
1. (most naive)

```
ssh -t -p port_num user@remote "sudo docker logs -f service_name"
```

2. ```
   ssh -t -p port_num user@remote << HERE
   > sudo su -
   > docker logs -f service_name
   > HERE
   ```
3. I created a file named `test.sh` containing lines 2 and 3 of my manual flow and then used this command:

```
ssh -t -p port_num user@remote 'bash -s' < /path_to_file/test.sh
```

4. ```
   ssh -t -p port_num user@remote "sudo docker logs -f service_name; bash"
   ```

I've run out of ideas now and any help is commended.

Comment: So, you want ssh with an initial command, but when that command is done, you want to remain in ssh session? `ssh -t -p port_num user@remote bash --init-file '<(echo "sudo docker logs -f service_name")'` maybe?

Comment: @Amadan thanks a lot! Your solution does work and is sufficient for my needs, but I expect just a little bit more. With your solution I'm identified at server as `bash-4.2$` (I see that after I press `ctrl + C` while viewing logs), and I don't have root privileges. I'd like to be logged in as root user after pressing `ctrl + C` as I normally do when I go through manual flow.

Comment: You can't be root after interrupting the sudo command, unless you launch ssh with root@remote. Anyway, I would consider using screen

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me:

```
ssh -t "servername" -l "username" "sudo docker logs -f service_name"
pause
```